# numbers after comma in Java

Tags: java

How do I get `n` numbers after a comma in Java?

```
...
double numb = 123.45;
void lastNumber(int n){
   // here
}
...
```

(in this example n = 2, so two numbers after the comma)

Comment: Do you mean decimal point?  `.` is a decimal point, `,` is a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit ugly:

```
public long getFraction(double num, int digits) {
    int multiplier = POWERS_OF_TEN[digits];
    long result = ((long) (num * multiplier)) - (((long) num) * multiplier);
    return result;
}
```

where `POWERS_OF_TEN` is an array of precomputed powers of ten (0=1, 1=10, 2=100, 3=1000, etc.)

Comment: +1: I would pass the `num` as a parameter and use `long` for the calculation, and `return` before the `}` ;) I have a similar function which uses an array of all the powers of ten, much faster than Math.pow().

Comment: @Peter Lawrey incorporated these suggestions in the answer.

Comment: You might want `powers of ten (0=1,` ;)

Answer (score 2):

- multiply it by 10^n
- floor or cast to int
- divide it by 10^n

or make use of

- BigDecimal

Answer (score 2):

double numb = 123.45 isn't actually 123.45, but something quite close to it in binary representation.

If you need EXACTLY 123.45 you need the [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class, like

```
BigInteger numb = new BigInteger("123.45"); // or
BigInteger numb = BigInteger.valueOf(12345, 2);
```

A short working program yielding 45:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal numb = BigDecimal.valueOf(12345,2);
        BigDecimal remainder = numb.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
        System.out.println(remainder.unscaledValue());
    }
}
```

BigIntegers are no fun to work with, but are really nice when dealing with financials. They're not fast but if you have only one number that shouldn't be a problem :)

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively simple. Rather than just give the answer,  please think about this. Forget Java - think about what you want to do from a mathematics point of view. From the question, you want numbers after the decimal point - the fractional part of the number - `0.45`. How can you get 0.45 from 123.45?

Think about what you need to subtract, and how do you get that number?
There is a math function, "floor", that gives you a number without its fractional part. (At least for positive numbers.)